# unzip a windows archive - some subdirectories are "permission denied"

Tags: shell, zip

I have a zip-file created on Windows, so - no specific permissions flags were assigned to the files inside it.

When I unzip the archive:

```
unzip filename.zip -d ~/path/to/destination
```

Some (only some, random) subdirectories 2 levels deep (and more) are not accessible to me. I can't seem to find any pattern... Seems like if a folder has only subfolders (and no files) in it - then it will be created inaccessible, with restrictive permissions flags.

I know I can just do `chmod -R 777 ~/path/to/destination` and see everything, but this really puzzles me. What is causing this?

And how can I create a zip file (in particular, on Windows) so that it can be extracted properly on linux?